# Confusion with a parameter definition from a datasheet

Tags: datasheet

I want to increase angles of [this](https://www.thorlabs.com/thorproduct.cfm?partnumber=GVS112) galvo scanner step by step like 50 mV at 20 kHz (my desired galvo step movement frequency). So each 50 μs the galvo should increase a small angle.

I cannot relate the following specs to my scenario:

[image]

What is meant by "Small Angle Step Response: The settling time for the mirror to stop moving once the drive signal is removed"? Does it mean even I increase the galvo very small angle it will take 400 μs to settle? In my case how can I related to 20 kHz? I try to figure out what at what maximum step frequency I can move the galvo.

Comment: "Small angle bandwidth 1 kHz" implies that expecting it to move at 20kHz is a completely hopeless quest. You can step it as fast as you like but it'll average out small steps into a slow continuous movement.

Comment: The thing is I dont understand the difference between the meaning of small signal bandwidth and small signal step response. If I use 400us this tells me the max step freq is 2.5kHz but if I use 1kHz the max step freq. becomes 1kHz. My question was "at what maximum step frequency I can move the galvo." So do you mean the answer is 1kHz? I appreciate a quantitative answer.

Comment: One cycle involves at least 2 steps, e.g. one up, one down. so the step response of 400us implies a max frequency of movement of 1.25kHz not 2.5 kHz. The "frequency response" measurement ( 1 kHz) is generally defined at the -3dB point, i.e. where the amplitude you get is 70% of the amplitude you ask for (at 1.25kHz you'd see less than that). So for example if you step it 0.1 degree at 2 kHz rate, alternately up/down, you can expect to see a roughly sinusoidal deflection 0.07 degrees peak to peak.

Comment: @user_1818839 How about in case of large movement like when doing raster scan. How fast can the galvo move from one end to the other? like moving 30° continually using a sawtooth waveform instead of small steps.

Comment: Improve the question then. I've already answered this little bit of it because I figured that's where you ere going.

Comment: Yes but they dont like evolving questions here :(

Comment: End to end, you're looking at the full travel bandwidth specification for a ballpark of course.

Answer (score 1):

Just so this question has an actual answer, the datasheet is telling you that it takes 400 microseconds for a small step. So trying to make a step every 50 microseconds is not going to work for this device.

Comment: Oh so the max step freq, I can achieve is only 2.5kHz?

Comment: The small signal bandwidth is specified as a maximum of 1 kHz, if you use a heatsink.

Comment: The thing is I dont understand the difference between  the meaning of small signal bandwidth and  small signal step response. If I use 400us this tells me the max step freq is 2.5kHz but if I use 1kHz the max step freq. becomes 1kHz. My question was "at what maximum step frequency I can move the galvo." So do you mean the answer is 1kHz?

Comment: If you make a single step and want the mirror to come to rest then you need to wait 400 microseconds. If you are continuously moving back and forth by small steps then the maximum frequency of this back and forth movement is 1 kHz.

Comment: How about in case of large movement like when doing raster scan. How fast can the galvo move from one end to the other? like moving 30° continually using a sawtooth waveform instead of small steps

Answer (score 0):

Bandwidth and settling time are related, but not the reciprocal of each other.

Bandwidth is usually defined as the frequency where the system output is half the nominal value. In your case, imaging you apply a sinusoidal drive, commanding a 1 milliradian amplitude motion. At 1 KHz, you'd be observing an actual motion of only half that value. At even higher frequencies still, the mirror would not follow the commanded position at all.

Settling time is a measure for how long it takes until the system output has settled within a certain margin of tolerable error (e.g. 1%). This can be due to finite bandwidth, that is, the system takes some time to slew to the target value. It can also be because there is some overshoot, in which case the settling time can be much longer than the time it takes just to slew to the target.

Anyhow, for first order systems (e.g. RC filters), both *are* related:
$$
f_{BW} \approx 0.35\frac{1}{\tau_r}
$$
Here, \$\tau_r\$ is the time it takes for the output to reach 90% of its final value.

I don't think an electromechanical actuator like your galvo can be accurately modelled as a first order system (2nd would be better I think), nor does the Thorlabs datasheet specify how they define the settling time (90%? 99%?), the formula above is not too far off.

Comment: How about in case of large movement like when doing raster scan. How fast can the galvo move from one end to the other? like moving 30° continually using a sawtooth waveform instead of small steps

Comment: Depends on your requirements (acceptable distortion and error). Certainly less than 1 kHz. If you need to know more precisely, the data from the datasheet is not enough.

Comment: The sawtooth is smooth except at the edges. This is where you'll see a lot of distortion. A few years ago I built a confocal imaging system with a very similar galvo, and it ran perfectly fine at 50 ms per line. Much smaller deviation though (few degrees).

Comment: Interesting. Some moves galvo in stair-step fashion some apply sawtooth waveform. They sync this with A-line scans. So one A scan per galvo step. And Im very confused about something here. For such imaging systems the A-line scan rates are in kHz levels. But galvano mirrors move much slower. Why do you think line scan rates are much higher than galvo?

Comment: 50ms is 200Hz. But the line cameras used are minimum 20kHz ect. I dont understand this point. Isnt the max scan speed dictated by galvo then?

Comment: How many pixels does the sensor have? Can you record *pixels* at a 20kHz rate, ie 1000 pixels per line?